# deleteOnExit not deleting file despite closing of stream writing to it

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

Relevant piece of code:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("", "");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
```

I'm running this as a local tomcat server run configuration via IntelliJ, and on quitting the server, it doesn't clean up the temp file. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: Did you stop the application server?

Comment: dan1st, yes. I even quit IntelliJ and made sure no stray processes are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File.deleteOnExit()` installs a shutdown hook on the current VM so your delete is only triggered if the VM performs a normal controlled shutdown.

For TOMCAT that would be via the `bin\shutdown.bat` or `bin/shutdown.sh` scripts within the TOMCAT installation.

However if your TOMCAT server could be running for *very* long periods you should avoid calling `File.deleteOnExit()` altogether as the files to delete are stored in a List which could (eventually) grow to huge size and lead to OutOfMemoryError.

This will not be a problem for a Tomcat instance that is re-started frequently, but would be an issue for high volume application server. If this different approach is needed, it is more reliable to keep track of temp files that are ready to delete in try...finally:

```
File temp = null;
try {
    ...
    temp = File.createTempFile("", "") ...
    ...
} finally {
    deleteOnExit(temp);
}

private static void deleteOnExit(File fileToDelete)
{
    if (fileToDelete != null)
        fileToDelete.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was considering going with a try-with-resources block, will give it a shot.