# deleting a file before jvm exit on which deleteOnExit is called

Tags: java, file, jvm, java-io

Create a java file object and call its deleteOnExit, then call delete programmatically and the close the JVM or program exits

Will deleteOnExit throw any exception as file was already deleted programatically?

Comment: What do you think? And if the JVM is exiting, does it matter?

Comment: Avoid `deleteOnExit` as it will cause OutOfMemoryError in long running servers, get into habit of using try-finally block to clean up as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017828/deleteonexit-not-deleting-file-despite-closing-of-stream-writing-to-it/63030811#63030811).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files is deleted already, nothing will happen. However, it might get deleted if you re-create it.

Even [`File#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()) doesn't throw an exception if the file does not exist, cannot be deleted. It would just return `false` in that case.

However, `File#deleteOnExit` saves a reference to the `File` that is kept [even if you delete the file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993692/10871900). Doing this multiple times will result in more and more references to deleted `File` objects hanging around in the heap, resulting in a memory leak and potentially in an `OutOfMemoryError` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540248/10871900)) since you also [cannot abort `File#deleteOnExit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()):

> Once deletion has been requested, it is not possible to cancel the request. This method should therefore be used with care.

Comment: – And that "saving a reference" makes `File.deleteOnExit()` dangerous when used within a long running server executable: the referenced `File` objects may pile up to an OOM.

Comment: This is why I noted it.

Comment: Some people need the explicit statement, subtle hints are wasted on them … 

Comment: Yeah, I added this.